# does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedindexchanged

I get this error on following line of code

> "does not contain a definition for 'RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged1' and no extension method 'RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged1' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.addreservation_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
```

And I don't know why this occur as I already have the selectedindexchanged method at code behind

```
 protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    }
```

So anyone know what problem is this? I tried clean the project and rebuild, but its not work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

May be you are missing opening bracket of the event that's why

```
 protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private Image fillImage;
private Text textLabel;

```
private float value = 0f;
private bool isDone = false;

void Awake() 
{
    this.fillImage = this.transform.Find("Fill").GetComponent<Image>();
    this.textLabel = this.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    
    
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    this.fillImage.fillAmount = 0f;
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (this.isDone)
    {
        if(this.OnDoneEvent != null)
            this.OnDoneEvent ();

        this.OnDoneEvent = null;
        this.OnchangeEvent = null;
        return;
    }

    if(this.OnchangeEvent != null)
       this.OnchangeEvent((int)(this.value *100));

    this.fillImage.fillAmount = this.value;
    this.textLabel.text = (this.value >= 1) ? "Done!" : (this.value * 100) + "%";
    this.isDone = (this.value >= 1)? true : false;
    
}
#region Get and set
public void setValue(float value )
{
    this.value = value;
}
public float GetValue()
{
    return this.value;
}

#endregion

#region Events
public void onChange(valueChanged method)
{
    this.OnChangeEvent += method;
}

public void onDone(ProgressDone method)
{
    this.OnDoneEvent += method;
}

public delegate void valueChanged(float value);
private event valueChanged OnchangeEvent;

public delegate void ProgressDone();
private event ProgressDone OnDoneEvent;

#endregion
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).